# Using unstack to concatenate values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling to wrap my head around the `unstack()` method. My DataFrame looks like the one below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Filename": ["A", "A", "A"], "Top 1 colour": [0, 0, 10], "Header": ["header", "header", "header"]})

    Filename   Top 1 colour   Header
0   A          0              header
1   A          0              header
2   A          10             header
```

And this is the outcome I'd like to achieve:

```
    Filename  header
0   A         0, 0, 10
```

I have used `set_index` because I want to keep my filename as a key field. I guess I can't concatenate my values with `unstack()`, but I would at least like to come close to my desired output. At the moment I get the following result:

```
df.set_index(["Filename"]).unstack()

              Filename                                          
Top 1 colour  A               0
              A               0
              A              10
Header        A          header
              A          header
              A          header
```

I have only just started using Python for data prep and this is a fairly common problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pandas.pivot_table`:

```
new_df = df.pivot_table("Top 1 colour", "Filename", "Header", 
                        aggfunc=lambda x: ",".join([str(i) for i in x]))
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
Header    header
Filename        
A         0,0,10
```